# How to connect two different Android devices using OpenTok?

Tags: android, opentok

I have gone through [OpenTok Android Tutorial](https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/android/basic-video-chat/step-1/). In this tutorial both, Publisher and Subscriber are the same user. How can I subscribe another user to this Session? In other words, How can I connect 2 different android devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you see OpenTokConfig.java file in the sample apps, you would notice a field

```
public static final boolean SUBSCRIBE_TO_SELF = true;
```

Set this property to false and then use the same token and sessionId in another android device to communicate.